# Executing dynamic condition in pyspark data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Data frame, target_df having 20 columns. Out of these 20 columns, 4 columns are mandatory, that is, these 4 columns should have value and should not be null and **no blank spaces** in these columns.
I want to filter the rows having null and blank spaces for these 4 columns.

```
This can be done with below condition.
filtered_df=target_df.filter((trim(target_df['Col 1'])==' ') | (target_df['Col 1'].isNull()) |
(trim(target_df['Col 2'])==' ') | (target_df['Col 2'].isNull()) |
(trim(target_df['Col 3'])==' ') | (target_df['Col 3'].isNull()) |
(trim(target_df['Col 4'])==' ') | (target_df['Col 4'].isNull()))

I want to make this dynamic and based on list of columns, i want to generate the condition.

mandatory_col=['col 1', 'col 2', 'col 3', 'col 4']
ln=[]
for ele in mandatory_col:
    str1="(trim(target_df['{}'])==' ') | (target_df['{}'].isNull())".format(ele, ele)
    ln.append(str1)
  
condition=' | '.join(ln)

print(condition):

(trim(target_df['Col 1'])==' ') | (target_df['Col 1'].isNull()) |
(trim(target_df['Col 2'])==' ') | (target_df['Col 2'].isNull()) |
(trim(target_df['Col 3'])==' ') | (target_df['Col 3'].isNull()) |
(trim(target_df['Col 4'])==' ') | (target_df['Col 4'].isNull())

filtered_df=target_df.filter(condition)  
when I try to execute above condition,  it throws error

ParseException: 
mismatched input ')' expecting {'COLLECT', 'CONVERT', 'DELTA', 'HISTORY', 'MATCHED', 'MERGE', 'OPTIMIZE', 'SAMPLE', 'TIMESTAMP', 'UPDATE', 'VERSION',....., IDENTIFIER, BACKQUOTED_IDENTIFIER}(line 1, pos 77)

The reason being condition is string and df filter takes pyspark.sql.column.Column.

please suggest how can I achieve executing string expression.
```

Comment: Hi @nl09, this is a very wrong way to ask a question. Please try to put a sample of data and try to ask a specific question and not a whole use case. I'll still try to help you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this string manipulation using expr.
I hope that you don't have spaces in your column names.
**Please note that what you are asking is very use case-based.
Read guidelines of *asking a question* on stackoverflow.**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

mandatory_col = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
str1 = ''
for ele in mandatory_col:
    str1 = str1 + '''trim('{}')'''.format(ele) + ''' is not null or ''' + '''trim('{}')'''.format(ele) + ''' = ' '  or '''

print(str1[:-5])

trim('col1') is not null or trim('col1') = ' '  or trim('col2') is not null or trim('col2') = ' '  or trim('col3') is not null or trim('col3') = ' '  or trim('col4') is not null or trim('col4') = ' '

filtered_df = target_df.filter(expr(str1[:-5]))
```

Comment: Thanks @Ambar Raghuvanshi
There are spaces in column name.

Using backquote instead of single quote helped to identify column name with space,
```str1 = str1 + '''trim(`{}`)'''.format(ele) + ''' is null or ''' + '''trim(`{}`)'''.format(ele) + ''' = ' '  or ''' ```

I feel, my question is valid.  Guidelines definitely stress on giving as much info as possible.
My question was clear enough for you to answer it  and also I have given the details to the extent possible.